# Customize iOS component to make something like pickerview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uislider

How can I make this picker/slider or whatever view?[image]

It is given to me by a designer and I have no Idea how to make it!

Comment: Hi, did you find the idea about this? could you help regarding this task.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a really easy task, there are different roads that you can take, but the one that makes more sense to me is [subclass](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html) `UIControl`.
`UIControl` is a subclass of `UIView`, the main difference is that it's ready to work with the target-action pattern and gives you the possibility to track touches without adding gesture recognizer.
A lot of UI interactive elements are concrete subclasses of `UIControl`, for instance `UIButton`.
Ray's site has interesting [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36288/how-to-make-a-custom-control) about how to do that.
Probably the harder part is integrating autolayout programmatically to make it adapt to any size of views.
This is the log hard road that provides the most reliable solution, but I think that you can achieve something similar compositing your own UIView subclass using a customized slider and some labels.

Comment: Can you give me more idea about slider? 
It is important for me that it behaves like uipickerview!

Comment: Which effect of the picker would you like to reproduce? my idea was a vertical slider, where the cursor is the yellow arrow, but if you need to "scroll" only the left side while keeping the arrow fixed, the slider is not ok.